# Create machine-readable logfiles

Tags: performance, logging

I'm currently developing a new device, which produces (text-)logfiles. There will be many devices of this type and I want to analyse the logfiles (for error-detection and statistics).

Until now, the log analysis was a side-product, logfiles of other devices were primary for peoples who tried to debug, so the information were human-readable ("fulltext"). With my automatic loganalysis-tool, I analysed these logfiles by searching for multiple keywords, which indicated interesting lines of the logfile. So the analysis was very intense, because I had to check one line for multiple keywords, and it's possible, that at the end, a line is irrelevant for my analysis. In case that the line is relevant for me, I sometimes need to parse the line costly by cutting out information at different positions in the line.
Altogether, the analysis of these logfiles is very slow.

With the new device, I like to implement more machine-readable logfiles (but still human-readable), what enables faster and easier analysis, also during implementation/extension of my log-analysis tool. I'm just wondering, whats the best practice?
My first idea is, to use a "trigger char" in a log message. We are in Germany, so I choosed the Dollar-sign, because we don't use it regularly. When I find this trigger-char, I know that I have to analyse this line (and I avoid scanning for multiple keywords). In addition, I thought that the most common case is a key-value-pair, which can contain the most important information of a log message.
Just in case, that I have multiple values (e.g. a list), I need also a machine-readble version of this. So my next idea was, to combine the trigger-char with a JSON-object. In the standard case, this only includes one key-value-pair and the loganalysis-tool will parse this for performance-reasons with simple string-operations and don't use a JSON-parser-library. But for the case that there is a list, I'll create a log message with a JSON-Array and parse this with a JSON-lib (in my case json-simple). On events, I'll insert a boolean (the "true" is not neccessary, just to stay JSON-conform).

So at the moment, a line looks like this:

```
05.01.2018 11:11:23: No new APN needed. ${"currentAPN":"m2m-net.sa.t-mobile"}
05.01.2018 11:11:51: can't open gpio 969. ${"openGPIO969failed":true}
```

Can I improve my concept in any way?

Side-note: I'm using a self-written Java-parser to analyse the logfiles of the older devices, which I would extend for the new project. Because of the very special log-message-"formats" (which grew by time), something like Logstash didn't work. Nevertheless, with ElasticSearch and Kibana I use the rest of the ELK-stack for my log-analysis and -visualization.

Side-note 2: The new device is a a kiosk-device with Android, so only one app running. We have full control over the system (device-owner) and also most parts of the hardware.

/edit: extended by event-message as mentioned in first comment
/edit 2: new side-note

Comment: If you want to continue supporting both human and machine readers, a venerable tradition is to always pair a unique numeric code with an informative text, the way e.g. SMTP does: "250 Email accepted."

Comment: But in the most cases, I do not have "events" (which I also want to support with JSON-"booleans") like your example, but key-value pairs. But in general a good point.

Comment: If some dev by mistake do a `log("Foo$bar")` it breaks your parser logic, if you use this approach.

Comment: Is it possible to generate two logs? One for humans an another one for statistics?

Comment: No, not directly, because I expect not only a "$", I expect a "${". But I'll also "prohibit" the usage of this char, not difficult in my environment, easy to control.

uhm. yeah. would be a possibility! interesting idea...

Comment: What kind of device is it? Perhaps there are some existing industrial de facto standard log file formats...

Comment: A kiosk-device with Android, so only one app running. We have full control over the system and even the whole hardware.

Comment: That should go into the question. Please don't comment your own question, but **edit your question** to improve it

Answer (score 6):

I've have had a lot of success using a "JSON-lines" format, where each line in the log file is a JSON object, e.g.

```
{"timestamp": "2018-01-05T11:11:23.000Z","Message": "No new APN needed.","currentAPN": "m2m-net.sa.t-mobile"}
{"timestamp": "2018-01-05T11:11:51.000Z","Message": "can't open gpio 969.","openGPIO969failed": true}
```

This format lends itself nicely to being indexed using log aggregation tools (we use ELK), while still being relatively human readable.  There are also a bunch of libraries which write this format (at least there are in the .Net ecosystem) - I'm a big fan of [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

You could log to some [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) database (or find some specialized logging library, there are many of them).

You could decide for a more structured format of your log file. For example, use [JSON](http://json.org/), [YAML](http://yaml.org/), [S-expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression), perhaps prefixed with some numerical code.

You should define and *document*, if your log file is textual, its [file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format), perhaps by specifying it in some [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) notation.

> Altogether, the analysis of these logfiles is very slow.

If your format syntax is well designed and regular (e.g. [LL(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser) grammar), [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) it should be quite fast.

For instance, if you use JSON notation for some parts of your log file, you could be sure that <kbd>TAB</kbd> characters are never used (since in JSON you'll encode them as `\t`), then the tab could be used as some field separator.

Try to use *existing* formats when possible (from your industry; perhaps there are some already). Otherwise, define and document well some [open format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_format) (that even your *competitors* would want to use). If possible, make your logging functions into some [open source software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software) library.